# Remove the first N items that match a condition in a Python list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

If I have a function `matchCondition(x)`, how can I remove the first `n` items in a Python list that match that condition?

One solution is to iterate over each item, mark it for deletion (e.g., by setting it to `None`), and then filter the list with a comprehension. This requires iterating over the list twice and mutates the data.  Is there a more idiomatic or efficient way to do this?

```
n = 3

def condition(x):
    return x < 5

data = [1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7]
out = do_remove(data, n, condition)
print(out)  # [10, 9, 8, 4, 7] (1, 2, and 3 are removed, 4 remains)
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

One way using [`itertools.filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) and [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import count, filterfalse

data = [1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7]
output = filterfalse(lambda L, c=count(): L < 5 and next(c) < 3, data)
```

Then `list(output)`, gives you:

```
[10, 9, 8, 4, 7]
```

Comment: Is it `ifilterfalse` instead of `filterfalse`? Having trouble importing `filterfalse`...

Comment: @wcarroll for python 2.x it is `ifilterfalse`

Comment: `ifilterfalse`  for python 2, just in case any py 2 developers getting import errors.

Comment: @JonClements Just out of curiosity, is using keyword arguments (i.e. `c=count())` within the lambda function signature the preferred way to create local variables within the lambda expression?

Comment: @wcarroll it's not remarkably pleasant - but for something like this it keeps scope to something relevant...

Comment: It would be nice if we don't have to keep checking the [first] condition each and every time once the max drop count is exceeded.

Comment: I've never heard of `filterfalse` - why use it instead of the built-in `filter` with a negated condition (in this case, `L >= 5 or next(c) >= 3`)?  Doesn't the existence of `filterfalse` break Python's golden rule, "There's only one correct way to do anything"?

Comment: Why are you reinventing `islice()`?

Comment: @wim It's easy not check the first condition every time; simply swap the two operators of `and`, and it will short-circuit after the maximum drop count has been reached.

Comment: @SvenMarnach it won't be the correct logic then (the counter would be incremented every time, rather than incremented conditionally)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It exists because negating a predicate is otherwise quite cumbersome: `filter(lambda x: not predicate(x), ...)` versus `filterfalse(predicate, ...)`.  In languages like Haskell it wouldn't make sense because you can do `filter (not . predicate)` using `.` for function composition but in python you have to use a `lambda` and the syntax is verbose. BTW: unrelated but this is also the reason why in some cases you have methods like `isEnabled` together with `isDisabled`. For example in Qt these are useful because you cannot negate the arguments of signals.

Comment: _[List comprehensions do the same thing better](http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.ppt)_ (Guido), i.e. filter + lambda is not pythonic.  This could be written `[x for x in data if x >= 5 or next(c) >= 3]` instead.

Answer (score 29):

Write a generator that takes the iterable, a condition, and an amount to drop.  Iterate over the data and yield items that don't meet the condition.  If the condition is met, increment a counter and don't yield the value.  Always yield items once the counter reaches the amount you want to drop.

```
def iter_drop_n(data, condition, drop):
    dropped = 0

    for item in data:
        if dropped >= drop:
            yield item
            continue

        if condition(item):
            dropped += 1
            continue

        yield item

data = [1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7]
out = list(iter_drop_n(data, lambda x: x < 5, 3))
```

This does not require an extra copy of the list, only iterates over the list once, and only calls the condition once for each item.  Unless you actually want to see the whole list, leave off the `list` call on the result and iterate over the returned generator directly.

Answer (score 23):

The accepted answer was a little too magical for my liking.  Here's one where the flow is hopefully a bit clearer to follow:

```
def matchCondition(x):
    return x < 5


def my_gen(L, drop_condition, max_drops=3):
    count = 0
    iterator = iter(L)
    for element in iterator:
        if drop_condition(element):
            count += 1
            if count >= max_drops:
                break
        else:
            yield element
    yield from iterator


example = [1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7]

print(list(my_gen(example, drop_condition=matchCondition)))
```

It's similar to logic in [davidism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39580319/674039) answer, but instead of checking the drop count is exceeded on every step, we just short-circuit the rest of the loop.

*Note:* If you don't have [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html) available, just replace it with another for loop over the remaining items in `iterator`.

Answer (score 4):

If mutation is required:

```
def do_remove(ls, N, predicate):
    i, delete_count, l = 0, 0, len(ls)
    while i < l and delete_count < N:
        if predicate(ls[i]):
           ls.pop(i) # remove item at i
           delete_count, l = delete_count + 1, l - 1 
        else:
           i += 1
    return ls # for convenience

assert(do_remove(l, N, matchCondition) == [10, 9, 8, 4, 7])
```

Comment: Note that the complexity of this approach is O(N * len(ls)), which is far from optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward Python:

```
N = 3
data = [1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7]

def matchCondition(x):
    return x < 5

c = 1
l = []
for x in data:
    if c > N or not matchCondition(x):
        l.append(x)
    else:
        c += 1

print(l)
```

This can easily be turned into a generator if desired:

```
def filter_first(n, func, iterable):
    c = 1
    for x in iterable:
        if c > n or not func(x):
            yield x
        else:
            c += 1

print(list(filter_first(N, matchCondition, data)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), we can use and increment a variable within a list comprehension:

```
# items = [1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7]
total = 0
[x for x in items if not (x < 5 and (total := total + 1) <= 3)]
# [10, 9, 8, 4, 7]
```

This:

- Initializes a variable `total` to `0` which will symbolize the number of previously matched occurrences within the list comprehension
- Checks for each item if it both:

  - matches the exclusion condition (`x < 5`)
  - and if we've not already discarded more than the number of items we wanted to filter out by:

    - incrementing `total` (`total := total + 1`) via an **assignment expression**
    - and at the same time comparing the new value of `total` to the max number of items to discard (`3`)

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehensions:

```
n = 3
data = [1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7]
count = 0
def counter(x):
    global count
    count += 1
    return x

def condition(x):
    return x < 5

filtered = [counter(x) for x in data if count < n and condition(x)]
```

This will also stop checking the condition after *n* elements are found thanks to boolean short-circuiting.

Comment: No need for the `counter` function, Python already has that built in: `filtered = (x for i, x in enumerate(data) if i > n or condition(x))`

Comment: That doesn't quite work because `enumerate` will iterate over the indexes but this needs to keep track of the number of elements that have already met the condition.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first *n* items in a Python list that match a condition, use **`itertools.dropwhile()`**:

`result = list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x < 5, data))`