# Set both condition and break in python for statement

Tags: python, django

I want to set condition and break in a for statement.

I set the condition that "contents" which has "likes" more than 24 
and result limits 7.

But I want to set the limit in the for loop because of the performance. 
How can I break the for statement if result counts 7?

Here is my code.

```
contents = Content.objects.filter(is_excluded=False).prefetch_related('comments', 'likes', 'dislikes').order_by('-created_date').all()[:400] 
result = [ v for v in contents if len(v.likes.all()) > 24][:7]
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3.8?

Comment: The performance problem isn't caused by the slicing, its (partly?) the evaluating of the length of likes instead of using count

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the first N items that match a condition in a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580063/remove-the-first-n-items-that-match-a-condition-in-a-python-list)

Comment: This is very similar question, just that the logic is reversed.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: How about getting first seven _contents_ objects?

Comment: django querysets are lazily loaded. So, queryset is not probably your bottleneck. More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using a list comprehension or getting the count like you do at all, you should annotate and filter and then slice the queryset

```
from django.db.models import Count
contents.annotate(num_likes=Count('likes')).filter(num_likes__gt=24)[:7]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you check my code edited and tell me that your code can be applied to me?

Comment: @HyeongJinKim - Why not give it a go?